# ICollection properties Sorting in ASP.Core using LINQ

Tags: linq, asp.net-web-api

How to sort Icollection properties.For example:

```
public  class INSTRUCTOR
{
    public int Id
    public string Name
    public PersonalDetails PersonalDetail
}

public class PersonalDetails
{
    public int Id;
    public string Firstname;
    public ICollection<Emails> Emails;
}

public class Emails
{
    public int Id;
    public string Email;
}
```

Now I have the list pages of instructor and I got all instructors like this:

```
var instructors = db.instructors.include(p=>p.personaldetails).Tolist();
```

I can sort using instructorName using the following Code:

```
instructors = instructors.OrderBy(i => i.PersonalDetail.Firstname).ToList();
```

But, I want to know how to do with using emails which is `ICollection`?

Comment: What property of the Emails collection do you want to order by? Number of emails for example would be `instructors.OrderBy(i => i.PersonalDetail.Emails.Count).ToList();`...

Comment: I want to order by email column which is in emails table

Answer (score 0):

In some way you're going to have to flatten the Email collection in order to sort the parent collection by it, either by applying some aggregate function or by for example joining it into a string.

If you for example make the assumption that the first Email address in the list is the primary address, then it could make sense to sort only by this item;

```
var orderedList = 
    instructors.OrderBy(i => i.PersonalDetails.Emails.FirstOrDefault()?.EmailAddress).ToList();
```

You could also choose to order by the "smallest" email address in the list by applying the Min() aggregate function;

```
var orderedList = 
    instructors.OrderBy(x => x.PersonalDetails.Emails.Min(e => e.EmailAddress)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.but am not saving all emails in one column like a@gmail.com, b@gmail.com(one column). Rather am saving as many individual columns with personal details id.like a@gmail.com(column) personaldetailsid(column) b@gmail.com(col) personaldetailsid (col).so there are 2 records is a personal details contains 2 emails.

Comment: And I want to sort by any one type of email.lets say there is one more column called email type, and I want to sort emails where email type is primary .